# Updating OSX Lion 10.7.5 to 10.8.4 so I can install xcode

Tags: macos, mac

The Mac App Store won't allow me to install xcode because I'd need osx version 10.8.4 or later. I did a system upgrade but I'm still at Mac osx lion 10.7.5. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: How did you "do a system upgrade?" Did you download OS X Mountain Lion from the App Store, install from the App Icon on Launchpad, restart your computer and wait for it to install?

Comment: @sameetandpotatoes, I just did a system upgrade on my computer.I have Lion, not mountain lion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to buy Mountain Lion or Mavericks in the AppStore. That will take care of the installation.  Mavericks is free, is supposed to be better, but there are some problems associated with it.

Before doing that, in any case, check your most frequently used applications to see if they are compatible with the OS X version you intent to install.  Then do a full backup and do disk permission checks in DiskUtilities before you upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, Xiaolei, however, when I try to download Mavericks, I get the error message: os x mavericks cannot be installed on this computer. Can you help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: @faigym, What computer model do you have?  If it cannot run Mavericks, then it probably can't run Mountain Lion either.  However you could install Xcode 4.6.3 on it.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I just found out from Apple that the original release date for my Macbook was in 2008 so this all won't work. thanks and I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @faigym In that case, you can still opt to install a previous version that is compatible with your OS X version at the [Apple Developer Site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action). You may have to register your Apple ID as a developer to use that site.